# Calculate number of lines in a div with its width in PHP

Tags: php

is there a way in PHP to count the lines a string will give with a given width and a given line-height?

For example, if I have this text:
Sed eget lorem lorem. Pellentesque tristique, quam vel fringilla porttitor,
neque elit suscipit nisl, id posuere magna libero congue ante.
= 2 lines

Sed eget lorem lorem. Pellentesque
tristique, quam vel fringilla
porttitor, neque elit suscipit nisl,
id posuere magna libero congue ante.
= 4 lines because the width is not the same

Edit:
My question was not clear.
As Jason McCreary said, I want to create a formula (based on font-size, string length, line-height) with PHP that will get me close.

If someone could send me in the right direction to do that I'd appreciate, because I tried to create that magical formula with no result.

I can't use JavaScript in the page.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally here is what I did:

```
$charWidth = 5.6;
$divWidth = 550;

$wrappedContent = wordwrap($originalContent, ($divWidth / $charWidth), "\r\n");
$explodedLines = explode("\r\n", $wrappedContent); 
$nbOfLine = count($explodedLines);

echo $nbOfLine;
```

No need to say that this is very approximative.

Answer (score 3):

No. PHP is a server side technology. It has no knowledge of the resulting HTML rendering.

Instead, you could:

- Use JavaScript. It's a client side technology and will provide much better results.
- Create a formula (based on font-size, string length, line-height) with PHP that will get you *close*.

#### Update

Check out functions like [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/strlen) and [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to help get you started with a PHP formula. They will help with line length and number of lines respectively. The line-height and font-size should be constant.

Comment: Yes in fact I want the sedond option. I know PHP is a server side technology. I did it with JS but then realized that I can't use JS in the page I'm working on. So PHP only...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only CSS

```
<div style="width: 10em; height: 1.2em; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
Now a long woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooord
</div>
```